# Zabbix monitors either of the two ports. If both ports are down, an alarm will be sent

Tags: zabbix

I have an old and new version of the program running on the server, with only one running at a time. Their ports will be either 8000 or 8080 randomly. I want to monitor either of these two ports with zabbix. As long as one port is listening, there will be no alarm. If neither port is listening, there will be an alarm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a trigger with [`and` operator](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/config/triggers/expression#operators). It will fire only when both ports are down.